# How do I make more than one \title in amsart?

Tags: titles, amsart

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

\title{Title1}
\maketitle

\newpage

\title{Title2}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

I would like to make multiple titles behave exactly as the first one. How can I do this?

Comment: `amsmart` isn't intended to be able to string together multiple articles.  adapting a book class to format chapter titles in this style might be an easier task.  (frequently different articles use incompatible packages; that is an important reason why no effort was made for `amsart` to serve as the basis for a "collection".)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the following lines into your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\let\@cleartopmattertags\relax
\newcommand\articleend{%
  \enddoc@text
  \let\authors\@empty
  \let\shortauthors\@empty
  \let\contribs\@empty
  \let\xcontribs\@empty
  \let\toccontribs\@empty
  \let\addresses\@empty
  \let\thankses\@empty
  \newpage
 }
\let\@wraptoccontribs\wraptoccontribs
\makeatother
```

Moreover, add the command `\articleend` at the end of an article, before defining the title and author of the next one.

Here is an example.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\let\@cleartopmattertags\relax
\newcommand\articleend{%
  \enddoc@text
  \let\authors\@empty
  \let\shortauthors\@empty
  \let\contribs\@empty
  \let\xcontribs\@empty
  \let\toccontribs\@empty
  \let\addresses\@empty
  \let\thankses\@empty
  \newpage
 }
\let\@wraptoccontribs\wraptoccontribs
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Title1}
\author{Author1}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-20]

\articleend

\title{Title2}
\author{Author2}
\maketitle
\lipsum[21-40]

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this with 2 titles and two different `\author` statements (one per 'thread'? No? Take a look on the author list  of the 2nd title then ;-)

Comment: :-))) Cooperation rules.

Comment: Ok, my first attempt at an answer was really poor, it behaves now a bit more reasonable.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for. The only anomaly I found is that in the second article, the (alternating) headers say ``author1 and author2", even though the title page of the second article (correctly) only has "author2" below the title. (In my case author1 and author2 are identical, so I suppose I could delete `\author{author2}` and format "author2" by hand on the second title page. Then the headers in the second article just say "author1".)

Comment: @GabeConant It seems I forgot to reset the macro for the short authors in my original solution. Fixed now.